# Track progress of sort in over-ridden compare method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, overriding

I'm currently sorting a (usually large) array like so:

```
private static void sortDocumentArrayByTime(Document[] sortedDocuments) {
    Arrays.sort(sortedDocuments, new Comparator<Document>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Document o1, Document o2) {
            return Long.compare(o1.getCreationTime(), o2.getCreationTime());
        }
    });
}
```

I want to track the progress of the sort and update a status bar I already have built, however I'm not quite sure how to update a counter. Obviously, I cannot reference a `sortCount` integer that is out of scope of the over ridden method, so what are my options? Do I even have any?

Comment: The problem with this idea is you would need to know what sort algorithm was been used.  Because you don't know where you are in the sort or how the values are been been moved about, I don't think that this is achievable with this approach...

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk that worked for me. Want to flip that into an answer so you can get the credit?

Comment: @PeterKazazes glad it worked for you! added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How accurate do you have to be? You could wrap an `int` (or `AtomicInt` even better) inside a new class, add a local final variable of that type to `sortDocumentArrayByTime()`. Each compare will increment the aforementioned `int` and show as progress `currInt / n^2`. Not very accurate but it's only a progress bar. You can try some other values than `n^2` since the average should be much lower (and the worst case might be bigger depending on the exact implementation Arrays is using the constants will be different etc).